# configurar python 3.6.2 y pycharm professional en ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Estoy tratando de configurar python3.6.2 (el que ya tengo instalado) en pycharm profesional, y cuando intento cambiar la version de python al crear un proyecto solo aparecen las versiones 2.7 y 3.5.

**¿Cómo puedo configurar esta versión en pycharm?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrégalo a tu proyecto nomás... Preferencias -> Proyecto -> Intérprete del proyecto -> ... -> más

Y ahi puedes...

[image: Captura de pantalla de PyCharm para agregar un nuevo intérprete]

En el signo de mas (<kbd>+</kbd>). En tu sistema puede estar ubicado en otra parte.